# Missing tags and some important fields in my odoo 14.0 UI

Tags: user-interface, odoo, odoo-14

I installed Odoo 14.0 with packaged installer supported by Odoo but after I installed, some important UI such as developer mode, debug code, and other are missing.

How to make them appear?

[image: ui]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install other module at least 1 module in order to see the developer mode and debug tools. For example, you can just install `sale` module, and once it is completed, you will see the tools appear.

I don't know the reason behind this though.